# c# how to make console.readline detect only specific numbers

Tags: c#

What I want:

Detecting an integer from the user, but only if it is between two specific numbers - for example, between 1 to 4.

How I'm currently doing it:

Using `Console.ReadLine()` to get the input, shortly followed by an '`if`' statement to verify that it is indeed between 1 to 4.

I am not satisfied with how many lines this takes up. Is there a more compact solution? (Learning c# in school, we recently finished '`for`' loops. I suppose I can just stick the `ReadLine` in a loop so that it will asking for a value until the detected number is below 5 and above 0, but is there a better way?)

Comment: You should use a `do... while` loop instead. For more info: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/370s1zax.aspx)

Comment: can you provide the code you have tried>

Comment: `int answer = 0;
do
{
    answer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
while(answer >= 0 && answer <= 4)`

Answer (score 0):

A `while` loop or a `do-while` loop should do the job just fine. Also note, in my example I introduce `int.TryParse` because if the user fills in something else then an `int`, an exception will be thrown.

[Microsoft MSDN Loops Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/f0e10e56(v=vs.90).aspx)

**while loop:**

```
int number = -1;
while (number <= 0 || number > 4)
{
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    int.TryParse(input, out number);
}

Console.WriteLine("Number is {0}", number);
```

**do-while loop:**

```
int number;
do
{
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    int.TryParse(input, out number);

} while (number <= 0 || number > 4);

Console.WriteLine("Number is {0}", number);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = 0;
Console.Write("Enter a value between 1 and 4");
while (!(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x) && (x > 0 && x < 5)))
    Console.Write("Wrong Value, try again: ");
```

Loop until you get a valid `int` and if you get valid `int` value then `x` should be `1,2,3,4` else run in loop.

`int.TryParse` method is used to check whether a given value is convertible to `int` or not and if convertible it returns converted value as `out` param